# Vue js call method function of different page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, components

Hey I am really new to VUE and for this project I have a button on one page which should trigger or call the function of another page. Everyone will be like why don't you have the button and function on same page as I am trying to learn basic part of how to call function of different page and then implement on my project. I am trying to make it easier and clear while I am asking question.

When I call the method function of `chairPage.vue` from `homePage.vue`, it throws an error saying `world` not defined on `homePage.vue`. Can anyone please explain why I am getting this error and what's the best way to solve this.

I have two pages one is  `homePage.vue` and another one is `chair.Vue`. I have a button on `homePage.vue` which should call the method function of `chairPage.vue`.

**Home Page**

```
<template>
   <div id="homepage">
     <b-button variant="info" @click="buttonClicked()">Click</b-button>

     <chairComponent ref="world"/>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import chairComponent from '@/components/chair.vue';

  export default {
  props: [],
  
  methods:{
    buttonClicked(){
      this.$refs.world.hello();
    }
  }

  }
</script>
```

**Chair Page**

```
<template>
   <div id="chairComponent">
      <p v-if="displayText == '1'"> HELLO WORLD </p>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: ['world'],
    data(){
      return{
        displayText:'',
      }
    },
    methods:{
      hello(){
        console.log('inside child component hello function');
        this.displayText = '1';
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) to your child component, and there [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch) on props and call function:

```js
Vue.component('Chair', {
  template: `
    <div id="chairComponent">
      <p v-if="displayText == '1'"> HELLO WORLD </p>
   </div>
  `,
  props: ['world'],
  data(){
   return{
    displayText:'',
   }
  },
  methods:{
    hello(){
      console.log('inside child component hello function');
      this.displayText = '1';
   }
  },
  watch: {
    world() {
      if (this.world) this.hello()
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      val: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
    buttonClicked(){
      this.val = true
      setTimeout(() => {this.val = false},0)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
 <div id="homepage">
   <b-button variant="info" @click="buttonClicked">Click</b-button>
   <chair :world="val" />
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey I tried to add the ```Vue.component``` on top of ```export default``` part and it throws an error saying ```Vue is not defined```

Comment: @Yahoo hey mate, no don't do that just change your existing components to use props like in my example

Comment: I was able to call the function but it only trigger one time. Is there a way I can make each time the button CLICK is clicked it will print out console.log('INSIDE CHILD COMPONENT HELLO FUNCTION') .

Comment: try now pls just updated my answer (just added `setTimeout(() => {this.val = false},0)`) in buttonClicked method

Comment: yup adding ```setTimeout(() => {this.val = false},0)``` worked for me. Can you explain what does that code mean.

Comment: sure, it means that you allow line above to be executed, (so setting the val which is prop that shows your message) then val is reset to null and you can again repeat call

Comment: got it . Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly fine in the below snippet

```js
Vue.component('Chair', {
  template: `
    <div id="chairComponent">
   </div>
  `,
  data(){
   return{
    displayText:'',
   }
  },
  methods:{
    hello(){
      console.log('inside child component hello function');
   }
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  methods:{
    buttonClicked(){
      this.$refs.world.hello();
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue-icons.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
 <div id="homepage">
   <b-button variant="info" @click="buttonClicked">Click</b-button>
   <chair ref="world" />
 </div>
</div>
```

I guess adding the components section in the homepage.vue might make it work

```
<template>
   <div id="homepage">
     <b-button variant="info" @click="buttonClicked()">Click</b-button>

     <chairComponent ref="world"/>

   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import chairComponent from '@/components/chair.vue';

  export default {
  props: [],
  // New changes added below 
  components: {
    chairComponent
  },
  methods:{
    buttonClicked(){
      this.$refs.world.hello();
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey I tried to add the ```Vue.component``` on top of ```export default``` part and it throws an error saying ```Vue is not defined```

Comment: Don't do Vue.component, just follow the changes that I have done in homepage.vue

Answer (score 0):

You can **$emit** from children to parent
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Child

```
hello () {
  ...//yours code
  this.$emit('customEvent', someValue)
}
```

Parent

```
<template>
  <child 
    @cutomEvent="function"
  />
<template>
```